# Could you elaborate [S + V + O + Adj + To inf. + O] structure?

Tags: grammaticality

I want to find more detailed explanation about the following pattern. For me, this grammatical structure sounds special.

- Windows makes it easier for you to install the program.
- You may find it difficult to locate the bug.

> Subject + Verb + Object + Adjective + To Infinitive +
>   Object

Please elaborate as complete as you can how to use this structure.

Comment: To me, the first example is ungrammatical. Did you mean "It makes **it** easier ... " ?

Comment: I cannot work out what you mean by "topic". If you mean, what would I look it up under, try "Dummy pronoun".

Comment: @ColinFine: I have changed the question a bit. Thanks.

Comment: These sentences all have object complements, and all have verbs that can take object complements. Is this what you're asking about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all,

> **S + V + O + Adj + *to* Inf + O**

is **not** a single construction. It is a string that can be the result of a large number of possible derivations.

Second, everything in such constructions depends crucially on what that ***V*** is. Not all predicates take infinitive complements, and of those that do, some allow *for* to mark the infinitive subject, and some don't; some have indirect object and others don't; some allow *to* to mark the infinitive verb, and others don't, etc.

There are a **lot** of variations, all depending on the matrix predicate. To see just how many, see [here](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf).

As to the two sentences provided,

> *Windows makes it easier for you to install the program.*

comes from something like

- *Windows makes [for it to be easier [for you to install the program]]*

i.e, there are three clauses here: one has *make* as its predicate, one has *be easier*, and the third has *install*. The middle clause has undergone Extraposition, which produces the dummy *it*, from

- ... *[for you to install the program] be easier*

Notice that *make* takes an infinitive without *to* (*make it work* but not **make it to work*), and auxiliary *be* is deleted before stative predicate adjectives (*make it tasty* but not **make it be tasty*). Details, details.

*Easy/easier*, the predicate of the second clause, takes an infinitive subject complement; if the subject of the infinitive is specified, it must take *for*.

The second sentence

> *You may find it difficult to locate the bug*

also has three clauses, and again the second one has a predicate adjective infinitive (*to be difficult*) with *to* deleted because it's a complement of *find*. That clause has also undergone Extraposition from

- ...*[(for you) to locate the bug] be difficult*

However, unlike the first sentence, the dummy *it* from extraposition has been [B-Raised](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) from being the subject of *(be) difficult*, to become the direct object of *find*. The last clause has lost its subject (*for you*) by Equi from the subject of *find*.

This is the kind of problem one encounters when treating grammar as composed of strings of words or word types. Grammar is constructions, not strings, and constructions are almost always governed by predicates. Without knowing the clause and predicates, it's impossible to talk about grammar usefully.

Comment: Hear, hear! But you buried the lede. Your final sentence should be raised to headline status. Anyway, +1.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is an "inflected infinitive", in that *you* is the subject of *to install*. It actually takes the "wrong" case, in that it takes object case, as is more easily shown in "It is easier for me to install the program." There, you can see that *me* is functioning as a subject.

I forget what this is called, but it does have a name.